# Sign up with undeliverable email in Devise/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

i'm using Devise (3.4.1) in my application, but i have a problem with signing up process. 
When user attempts to sign up with valid but undeliverable email address, ActionMailer raises Net::SMTPFatalError exception and user see "Something went wrong" message.

Is there any workaroud to have flash[:error] message on registration form instead of that?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do, the simplest is to put the sendmail call in a begin/rescue block, like so:

```
begin
  # Try to send mail
rescue Exception => e
  flash[:error] = e.message # OR a more readable error like "cannot deliver email"
  render :new
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, i can solve problem this way, but to do this i have to inherit Devise::RegistrationsController. I think that must to be some workaround without touching Devise code.